# Backbone View not loading

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I apologise for what is probably an incredibly simple mistake, but my backbone view is not loading.  The code works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9suvj3m/1/ however in my code it does not work. I assume I am making a mistake either where I include the scripts in the jade file, or am not waiting for something to load in the js? If I insert alerts, an alerts before defining myview triggers, but nothing after that.

Edited to take into account comments. Main issue still not fixed.

index.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css")
    title Homepage

  body
    #body-js
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js")
    script(src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js")
    script(type='text/javascript' src='scripts/main.js')
```

scrips/main.js

```
var myview, view;

myview = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
  return $("#body-js").html("hello");
  }
});

view = new myview({
  el: '#body-js'
});
```

edit: Using the non minified version of backbone I see that the error is at `if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {` - line 1538. I assume this means that `_` is underfined. Is this a correct assumption, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or not but in your code there `return $("body-js").html("hello");` it should be `#body-js`. Just to be sure, you can also replace it by `this.$el.html('hello');`. And finally, your styles should be in the `head` of your page.

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks! Also thanks for the tip re styles.

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: Nope, didn't fix the problem of the backbone view not loading.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Can you show us the page in context?

Comment: There is no context - I have stripped everything else out. There is one error and it is in backbone-min.js. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which I guess may be the cause.

Comment: You need to see in the stack where the error starts in your code. Unfold the error, and see where the line is referencing your main.js file.

Comment: Thanks YoannM - Unfolding I get this: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function backbone.js:1563  U backbone.js:1563(anonymous function) main.js:3`

Comment: Try to put your scripts after your `#body-js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your scripts after your `#body-js`.

Backbone doesn't find the dom element to make its view.

Because your code is executed before the dom is ready.

Which is not the case on jsFiddle. It's executed `onDomready`.

You also need to tabulate one more level right after the line `html(lang='en')`.

I've finally found your problem... Your underscore is way too old (1.1.6).

Use the latest version (1.7.0).

Comment: I tried that, but still no dice. It is probably the correct place to have them so thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you make an edit of your question with your new snippets, after the tips you received, please? Just to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: In your jade file, don't you need to tab everything after the line `html (lang='en')`? Because with this tabulation it does something like `<html></html><head>[...]</head><body>[...]</body>`

Comment: questions edited. The jade misindentation was an error here, not in the code. Thanks for comments YoannM

Comment: That was it! Should have checked that, but thanks for all your help YoannM!